# How to build an array of enums in Objective-C as NSNumber and then return these to enums again?

Tags: arrays, objective-c, enums, nsnumber

Having read several Q&As on this, it seems that the only way to build an array of predefined enums in Objective-C is to first convert to NSNumber. For example:

```
NSArray *fruits;

    fruits = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
             [NSNumber numberWithInt:enumValue1],
             [NSNumber numberWithInt:enumValue2],
             [NSNumber numberWithInt:enumValue3],
             nil];
```

This solved my first problem and allowed me to add enums to the array - and then shuffle (randomise) their indices, which was the whole point of building an array in the first place. However, is there any way of re-converting these NSNumbers back to their original enum form, effectively reversing the conversion, so that they can be evaluated against the original enum values?

The alternative, to also convert the comparator to an NSNumber at every evaluation, is at the very least ugly. In addition, I am getting some warnings during these evaluations, such as:

> Comparison between pointer and integer ('ORKPredefinedTaskMovementOption' (aka 'enum ORKPredefinedTaskMovementOption') and 'NSNumber * _Nonnull')

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: `ORKPredefinedTaskMovementOption reconvertedValue = [fruits[0] integerValue];` should do the trick.

Comment: At least eyeball ```NS_ENUM``` and ```NS_OPTIONS``` - you may find what you were not looking for. Even there you'd need to convert to ```NSNumber``` to store in an array but conversion to and from is relatively painless. That warning shows you did not convert correctly and are comparing the pointer value to the enum value, something as suggested by @Larme should do the trick.

Comment: Gosh, that was too easy when you know how. Thanks @Larme & @skaak!!

Comment: And of course in modern ObjcC you'd write the above as `fruits=@[@(enumValue1),@(enumValue2),@(enumValue3)];`